# You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf, ieeetran, input, bibliographystyle

I have the following `overleaf` project structure:

```
root
├──IEEEtran.cls
├──IEEEtran.bst
├──Introduction.tex
├──main.tex
├──Related_Work.tex
├──References
   └──refererences.bib
```

My `main.tex` file contains the following:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{soul} % for highlights

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}

\title{Manuscript Title}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
   
\end{abstract}
\begin{IEEEkeywords}

\end{IEEEkeywords}

\input{Introduction.tex}
\input{Related_Work}

% Reference list
\bibliographystyle{./IEEEtran}
\bibliography{References/references} 

\end{document}
```

I have only 2 reference list in References/references.bib

```
@article{b1,
  title={AMUSE: Empowering users for cost-aware offloading with throughput-delay tradeoffs},
  author={Im, Youngbin and Joe-Wong, Carlee and Ha, Sangtae and Sen, Soumya and Chiang, Mung and others},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing},
  volume={15},
  number={5},
  pages={1062--1076},
  year={2015},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{b2,
  title={Cooperative data offload in opportunistic networks: From mobile devices to infrastructure},
  author={Lu, Zongqing and Sun, Xiao and La Porta, Thomas},
  journal={IEEE/ACM Transactions on Networking},
  volume={25},
  number={6},
  pages={3382--3395},
  year={2017},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Nothing in the `Introduction.tex` file but the heading, only the following in the `Related_Work.tex`:

```
\section{Related WOrk}

We refer to the methods in \cite{b1} and \cite{b2}
```

But the output isn't showing the citations.

Error:

```
You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography.
Citation 'b1' on page 1 undefined on input line 6
```

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with  your code, as far as I can tell, though it requires running pdflatex, then bibtex, then pdflatex two more times to get the right result. I'm not an overleaf user, so I don't know how it works, but are you sure it's doing all of that? If you only run pdflatex once without running the other commands, you'll get the result you show.

Comment: @frabjous Overleaf does automatic compilation using `latexmk` so bibliography processing works seamlessly.

Comment: Try putting your `.bib` file in the root folder of your project and see if that solves the problem. The `\bibliography` command does not take a path as an argument, it takes the name of a `.bib` file only.

Comment: @AlanMunn I have done this, and changed `\bibliography{References/references}` to
`\bibliography{references}`, still the same effect.

Comment: Maybe you need to add the `.bib`? In my IEEEtran paper, I write `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} \bibliography{IEEEabrv, ref/ref.bib}` and it works out fine.

Comment: @TeddyvanJerry unfortunately, adding `bib` didn't help.

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) I don't see this problem with a project I created from the current IEEE Conference template and substituted your code: https://www.overleaf.com/read/hbhwnkcmczyq (I'm not sure what version of IEEEtran.bst you're using. But that wouldn't normally affect this, I only mention it because it is a difference between my test project and your own project structure.) If you're unable to get this working, please write to us at support@overleaf.com and we'll take a look at your whole project to see what might be causing this.

Comment: @PaulGessler ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Paul for your help. Here's how this was fixed.

a. Deleted the file `IEEEtran.bst` (which was initially empty, strange).

b. In the `main.tex` changed:

```
\bibliographystyle{./IEEEtran}
```

to:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```